# Extracting data from object by string

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var object =  {item : {id : "51524512541"}};
```

Some service is passing this string:

```
var str = "item.id";
```

And I want to extract the id (51524512541).

Splitting by `.` (dot) is an option, but the `object` may be very deep.

Can maybe eval with try catch can help here somehow?

Comment: try `_.get` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get

Comment: If the objects are very deeply nested and strangely keyed, or with arrays in the mix, a normalized solution might be in order. Like lodash's `get` or one of the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key).

Comment: @marzelin jinx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` for this - go through array of indices and dive deeper into the object:

```
str.split('.').reduce((a, i) => a[i], object)
```

Explanation:

First, `str` is split into array, forming:

```
['item', 'id'].reduce((a, i) => a[i], object)
```

So You have array of indices, that You want to "visit". Now You call `reduce` on it - it takes the indices one by one and calls a function on every one of them (the `i`) and result of previous call (the `a`) and returns `a[i]`, so it "dives" one level deeper in the object. The first call has no "previous result" available yet, so it takes the `object` as initial value.

So the real calls look like this:

```
i = 'item', a = {"item":{"id":123}} -> result a[i] is {"id":123}
i = 'id', a = {"id":123} -> result a[i] is 123
```

Comment: @Shazam: See @MichaelCurry's fiddle - `res` contains the result value (not `object[res]`).

Answer (score 1):

You could break the string up using split:

```
var splitStr = str.split('.')
```

Then use reduce to dive into the object.

```
const reducer = (accumulator, index) => accumulator ? accumulator[index] : accumulator
splitStr.reduce(reducer, object)
```

This should give you the result.

Check out more on reducers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Alternative option, which is probably more efficient:

```
let result = object
for(let str of splitStr) {
  if(!result) break;
  result = result[str]
}
```

Here's a JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/h75dxsrz/15/

Comment: `reduce` would be more appropriate here since you convert array to something else

Comment: Yeah, you're completely right, never really touched a reducer before so this is a great example! I'll update my answer.

Comment: nice, but it fails with path `x.y` and an empty object `{}`. ;)

Comment: Something like `(accumulator, index) => accumulator ? accumulator[index] : accumulator` to fix this?

Comment: I'd use `for...of`. You can break from a loop early.

Comment: Thank you. Can you put it in jsfiddle. I really dont get the it. tanks

Comment: Added one to the answer :)